# How to bind two dimensional data value to checkbox v-modal in buefy table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

I have one array which is in below format.

```
let tableData = [
        {
          'id': 123,
          'subArray': [
            { 'subId': 'ABC123', 'name': 'subElement1', 'ischecked': true },
            { 'subId': 'DEF123', 'name': 'subElement11', 'ischecked': false }
          ]
        },
        {
          'id': 456,
          'subArray': [
            { 'subId': 'ABC456', 'name': 'subElement2', 'ischecked': true },
            { 'subId': 'DEF456', 'name': 'subElement22', 'ischecked': true }
          ]
        },
        {
          'id': 789,
          'subArray': [
            { 'subId': 'ABC789', 'name': 'subElement3', 'ischecked': false },
            { 'subId': 'DEF789', 'name': 'subElement33', 'ischecked': true }
          ]
        },
        {
          'id': 121,
          'subArray': [
            { 'subId': 'ABC012', 'name': 'subElement4', 'ischecked': false },
            { 'subId': 'DEF012', 'name': 'subElement44', 'ischecked': true }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

I am using Buefy table to render the data in below way.

```
<b-table :data="tableData">
        <template slot-scope="props">
          <b-table-column label="ID" field="id"> {{ props.row.id }}</b-table-column>

          <b-table-column label="SubArray" field="subArray">
            <span v-for="sub in props.row.subArray" :key="sub.subId">
              <b-checkbox v-model="sub.isChecked">{{ sub.name }}</b-checkbox>
            </span>
          </b-table-column>

        </template>
      </b-table>
```

**Problem:** When i check any of the checkbox, it will show the checkbox Checked just for which we clicked, but the 'isChecked' value for all row in array is updated to "True".

**Example:** If i check the checkbox for "subElement22", then subElement11, subElement33 and subElement44 will also update.

**Expected:** When i click any checkbox, value related to just that row should be updated not other.

How can i bind v-modal ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem because you didn't share all your code. Can you please try this:

```html
<div v-for="sub in tableData" :key="sub.subId">
      <div v-for="subsub in sub.subArray" :key="subsub.id">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="subsub.isChecked"> {{subsub.name}}
     </div>
</div>
```

What I am doing here creating 2 for loops. First one is for the tableData array and other is for subArrays. With this code all checkboxes act just like you want.